# Nominatim-docker only displaying one earth "tile"

Tags: docker, leaflet, nominatim

I have installed docker recently and try to build/run [nominatim-docker](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/3.4) version 3.4. I followed the step 1-4. Since I didnt do any advance configure and using any configure for incremental update, I did not do step 5 or 6.

I am not sure what are the potential cause of this that the map is not displaying correctly (only displaying one tile) while the mini-map working fine. 
I am not sure what causes this issue or how to address it.

This might not be the most detailed question, but I am not sure what to include.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved in later version of nominatim-docker

https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/pull/1581